# How to refresh the DataSource on a WinForms DataGridView?

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, refresh

I populate the GridView.DataSource from a EntityFramework Model:

```
gwTimeLog.DataSource = _entities.TimeLogs;
```

When a new row is added to the _entities, I try to update the grid (tried using the same statement as above, setting it null, then back to _entities.TimeLogs, etc...), but the grid simply won't update.  Even though _entities.TimeLogs actually does contain the new rows.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is to have the gridview connected to the BindingList rather than the List.

Answer (score 13):

OLD ANSWER: Did you try calling GridView.DataBind()?

Woops, I thought this was a WebForms DataGrid.

If you're on WinForms, you might want to look into the BindingSource class.  Binding to that class instead of straight to your list will provide update notification, etc.

The following code works for me:

```
        List<Person> names = new List<Person>();
        names.Add(new Person(){
            FirstName = "Steve",
            LastName = "Jobs"
        });
        names.Add(new Person()
        {
            FirstName = "Bill",
            LastName = "Gates"
        });

        BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = names;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = source;

        names.Add(new Person()
        {
            FirstName = "Steve",
            LastName = "Balmer"
        });

        source.ResetBindings(false);
```

Comment: BindingSource @ MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx

Comment: Still does not work.  I simply want the grid to update.  I don't really need update notification.  Maybe it's the underlying data which is the Entity Framework.

Comment: i posted the code above.  the underlying data shouldn't matter.  did you call ResetBindings()?

Comment: This does not work when the BindingSource references an Entity Framework query.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this doesn't work after I've updated a form-level variable (re-fetched from REST service).

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = null;
dataGridView.DataSource = listOfSomething;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  For example, is there any reason why setting the DataSource to null and then to something else works?

Comment: This code causes updating the whole data grid contents, while just setting data source to the same value again - is not

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. I've had ResetBindings(False) work on other forms, but for some reason it stopped when I went to Entity Framework.

Answer (score -1):

```
 grid.EndEdit();
 BindingSource.EndEdit();
 _entities = new dbEntities();
 firmeBindingSource.DataSource=_entities.TimeLogs;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)