# Refreshing DataGridView?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I would like to provide a "Refresh" button on a form containing a DataGridView object bound to a MySQL database.  I have gotten screens without columns populated from a query with calculated fields by "new"ing the MySQLCommand, MySQLDataAdapter, MySqlCommandBuilder and DataSet objects and rerunning the query and reloading the binding source to the DataGridView object.

For ones that have calculated columns, this does not work.

Surely, there must be some way to have a DataGridView object reload from the DB.

I am using SharpDevelop C# 5 with .NET framework 4.0, MySQL Community Server 5.3.33 and MySQL Data Connector/.NET V 6.7.4

Any leads much appreciated!

---

Jesse and Brian,

I am doing WinForms - sorry for not being clear.  I have just worked out a solution.  First, just executing what was run in the initial load is not enough.  I found one must "new" the MySqlCommand, MySQLDataAdapter, MySqlCommandBuilder and DataSet objects, then run the data fetch as in the form load.  Also, this cannot be called while doing anything that looks or smells like "editing" or it will throw an exception.  I wanted my form to refresh just after edit, so I put a timer on the form and enabled it at the end of the RowValidated event and let the timer call the ReloadGrid routine.  Also, if the user is on, say row 822, I found the focus went to row 0 and cell 0, so I save the current row and cell to a point and then set the focus back after the data refresh.

Comment: It's the same way you loaded it the first time.

Comment: This should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015327/how-to-refresh-the-datasource-on-a-winforms-datagridview

Answer (score 0):

```
private void BindGrid(){
//retrieve data

//bind
DataGridView.DataSource = dataSource;
DataGridView.DataBind();
}

//call BindGrid() anytime you need to refresh data, for example in a button event click handler
```

Comment: DataGridView is a Winforms control and doesn't have a DataBind method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx

Comment: Well why didn't you say so lol. You should always state that you are using WinForms or it will most of the time be assumed you are using WebForms.